# Auto compile sub project of a website solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, compilation, project, config

Is to possible to make a configuration entry (web.config). That automatically compiles a referenced project(for example a class library) when the site runs? This would be easier for me to maintain on my hosting server. Otherwise i have to always recompile the files and upload  them again for every small change.

So is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

The App_Code folder within a .Net web project compiles at runtime... you can put cs files in there and modify them directly on the web server if you need. Then to adopt the change made in most cases you only need to recycle the application pool.

see this explanation on msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23(v=vs.80).aspx